# ReportViewer Zooming issue with IE 10 browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssrs-2008, internet-explorer-10, report-viewer2010

While zooming Reports in IE10 using the zoom option in ReportViewer height exceeds the frame.
I am using ReportViewer inside an iframe. when I Zoom above 100%(150%, 200% and 500%) Report height increases and 
not able to view or scroll to the top of the Report. It also hides the Toolbar and not abe to select the zoom dropdown or any other controls.
I changed the browser mode to IE7 then it works fine. But not working in IE8, IE9 and IE10.
Tested in windows 7 SP1 and Windows 8, 8.1 and issue exists in all the three.